# Log to console / error window?

Tags: templating

I'm trying to get this code working

```
{% if article_id is defined %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.id(article_id).first() %}
{% endif %}
```

The code itself is unimportant, what's relevant is that I'm currently working outside of the context where I would rendering an article. This particular code happens to be broken, and I would like to fix it via inspecting `{{ article_id }}`. Except I can't, because:

```
Template Error

A template that extends another one cannot have a body.

---

{% extends "_base" %}

{% if article_id is defined %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.id(article_id).first() %}
    {{ article_id }}
{% endif %}
```

Now there's a variety of ways that I could solve this issue, but I'm wondering what's the best option. Ideally it would be something like `{{ craft.log(article_id) }}` - ie. a function would still produce the Template Error, but at also let me see the value / other information about `article_id` (either in the error window, or on the javascript console log).

How should I implement the logging behavior that I'm looking for?

Comment: For the record, I solved the issue with the code above before I even posted this question. It was just the example I had on hand

Answer (score 2):

If you have [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) enabled, then you have access to Twig's `dump` method that lets you inspect variables.

```
{{ dump(article_id) }}
```

Or, if you're feeling more adventurous, there is a debugging library called [Kint](https://raveren.github.io/kint/) that there is a Craft [plugin](https://github.com/mildlygeeky/craft_kint) for to help debug templates.

Comment: Dump is a very useful, but it still doesn't let me access the information when there's a Template Error ,which is my main issue. Suppressing, or writing to, the Template Error page is the main thing that I need

Comment: Oh... maybe I'm not following.  You want to still be able to write to the page (or a log file) even when there's a Twig error?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to either write to the Twig Error page, a log file, the browser log, or similar. I just looked at Kint (which is pretty nice) and it looks like it displays the errors with `{{ render }}` style code. It occurs to me that if it displayed with the `{% render %}{% endrender %}` style, it could bypass this particular Template Error.

(sorry if that's not more clear!)

Comment: Hrm... I'm not sure it's possible do to what you're looking for then. When a Twig error occurs, an exception is thrown and the rest of the Twig template isn't processed, so there'd be no chance for you (or a plugin) to do anything else from Twig. The best you could do is have a plugin that listened for Yii's onError and onException events.